# Getting application config in doWithSpring closure with a Grails 3 application

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

Grails 3 allows authors to use startup hooks similar to the ones provided to Grails 2 plugins.  I'm looking at defining beans in the `doWithSpring` closure, and I'd like to pass values into a new bean based on some configuration values.  I can't figure out, however, how to get the grailsApplication instance or the application configuration.  How do you do this with Grails 3?

Comment: I spent a while looking around and could not find any of the plugins at that point doing this.. I ended up pulling in the config from the actual app and passing the config element to the plugin.. Not pleased with it myself to be honest.. https://github.com/vahidhedayati/RemoteSSH/tree/grails3

Comment: "Not pleased with it myself to be honest." - @vahid See my answer below.  In your plugin you can just refer to the `config` property.  Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Your plugin should extend `grails.plugins.Plugin` which defines the `getConfig()` method.  See https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/9f78cdf17e140de37cfb5de6671131df3606f2fe/grails-core/src/main/groovy/grails/plugins/Plugin.groovy#L65.

You should be able to just refer to the `config` property.

Likewise you can refer to the inherited `grailsApplication` property which is defined at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/9f78cdf17e140de37cfb5de6671131df3606f2fe/grails-core/src/main/groovy/grails/plugins/Plugin.groovy#L47.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, sorry I meant to have said not pleased with my own figuring out or work around. Should play around first before writing this... The Q that comes to mind... plugin descriptor certainly extends Plugin which then attempts to create the config bean. Should the config class https://github.com/vahidhedayati/RemoteSSH/blob/master/src/groovy/grails/plugin/remotessh/SshConfig.groovy#L3 now also extend grails.plugins.Plugin for this to work ?

Comment: "Should the config class now also extend grails.plugins.Plugin for this to work ?" - No.  Only the plugin class should extend `grails.plugins.Plugin`.  It isn't clear from looking at the code on your `grails3` branch what it is that you are really trying to do but based on the version that is on the `master` branch, you probably want to register the `SshConfig` bean in `doWithSpring` and just inject the config values from there. I would also use `GrailsApplicationAware` instead of injecting the `grailsApplication` bean explicitly, but it may not be needed at all.

Comment: Some of the code on your `master` branch is nonsensical to me.

Comment: Hi Jeff I have got it working so will add the full step by step answer in a minute to this question. In regards to the nonsensical did you mean the Duplicate Java / Groovy classes :) (was  my first plugin and  a fine mess ) Burt kindly fixed the mess and provided the groovy variation. I think the Groovy classes are fine on their own can clean it up and release under 2 if you wish.

Comment: This is useful information for folks new to writing Grails 3 plugins, however the question was targeted at Grails 3 applications, not plugins.  There is more detail to found at http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Getting-application-config-in-doWithSpring-closure-with-a-Grails-3-application-td4659165.html.

Comment: @BudJB For applications you can override `doWithSpring` in your `Application` subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Under Grails 3, I took Jeff Scott Brown's advice and used GrailsApplicationAware instead:

This is how you go about setting up a configuration bean:

So in your new plugin descriptor you need to change grails 2 style def doWithSpring to a ClosureDoWithSpring as below:

Notice in Grails 2 we injected grailsApplication, in grails 3 all we do is declare the bean:

```
/*
    def doWithSpring = {
        sshConfig(SshConfig) {
          grailsApplication = ref('grailsApplication')
        }
    }
*/
   Closure doWithSpring() { {->
        sshConfig(SshConfig)
        } 
    }
```

Now to get your plugin configuration:

src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/remotessh/SshConfigSshConfig.groovy

```
package grails.plugin.remotessh

import grails.core.GrailsApplication
import grails.core.support.GrailsApplicationAware

class SshConfig implements GrailsApplicationAware {

    GrailsApplication grailsApplication


    public ConfigObject getConfig() {
        return grailsApplication.config.remotessh ?: ''

    }

}
```

grails.plugin.remotessh.RemoteSsh.groovy:

```
String Result(SshConfig ac) throws InterruptedException {

        Object sshuser = ac.config.USER ?: ''
        Object sshpass = ac.config.PASS ?: ''
...
```

This is now your configuration object being passed into your src groovy classes. The end user application would pass in the sshConfig bean like this:

```
class TestController {

    def sshConfig

    def index() {
        RemoteSSH rsh = new RemoteSSH()
      ....
        def g = rsh.Result(sshConfig)
    }
```

Edited to add, just found this :) which is relevant or duplicate question:

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Getting-application-config-in-doWithSpring-closure-with-a-Grails-3-application-td4659165.html

Comment: I started the thread on the grails dev google group since at the time there wasn't a lot of traction here.  Just for context :)

Comment: Hah and yes I binder them both here  so  for others in the future a lot  less pain and also different approaches issues of the same kind.  It's all good stuff :)